# Как узнать, является ли модуль стандартным для Python или нет?

Tags: python, зависимости, requirements.txt

Вопрос возник, т.к. я создал файл `requirements.txt` командой `pipreqs`, и на мое удивление в него записалось всего три модуля.

Answer (score 2):

Есть несколько способов узнать, является, ли модуль стандартным (или built-in) для python.

1. Можно посмотреть вручную в [перечне в документации](https://docs.python.org/3/py-modindex.html#cap-s). Так себе предложение, но читать документацию всегда полезно (imho)
2. В самом проекте можно воспользоваться [`sys.builtin_module_names`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.builtin_module_names). Результатом будет кортеж, который содержит имена всех built-in модулей, скомпилированных в этот интерпретатор Python. Следовательно можно спросить

   ```py
   >>> import sys
   >>> "sys" in sys.builtin_module_names
   True
   ```

   Только есть загвоздка и данный перечень не содержит импортированных модулей, даже если он стандартные. Здесь появляется разделение, что считать стандартным модулем

   ```py
   >>> import sys
   >>> import os
   >>> "os" in sys.builtin_module_names
   False
   ```

   В действительности, можно написать функцию обработки, но не здесь. Следующий пункт нам поможет
3. В python версии 3.10 появилось, то к чему мы стремились в этом ответе.
   [sys.stdlib_module_names](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.stdlib_module_names) возвращает `frozenset`, который содержит имена стандартных модулей.

   ```py
   >>> import sys
   >>> "os" in sys.stdlib_module_names
   True
   ```